# jQuery sortable margin issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, margin, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm having two sortable lists where I can add items from the first list to the second list. The default behavior removes the element from the source list, but that's not what I want (I want it to be copied to the destination list), so I made some adjustments to clone the moved element in the source list before it gets deleted.

It works, but I have weird issues with margins on cloned elements. See for yourself:

**This is before:**

[image]

**After some dragging, margin inconsistencies appear:**

[image]

I have a jsfiddle of the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/JNbsX/

I've tested it on Chrome and Firefox and the issue exists in both browsers. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It appears to have something to do with the `display: inline-block;` as setting the style to `display: inline-block;` on the jqueryui sortable sample has the same effect.  No expert on css but probably worth investigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure why it's happening, but some of your list items are coming out with `display: list-item;` instead of `display: inline-block;`, despite your css.

Setting the `ul > li` to just `li` seems to fix the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/RichardTowers/rZuRt/

Answer (score 0):

You still can use `display: inline-block` but you need to add white space before and after all item.

```
$('ul#source').sortable({
    helper: 'clone',
    connectWith: 'ul#dest',
    start: function(event, ui) {
        $("ul#source > li").eq($(ui.item).index()).after(
            $(ui.item).clone().addClass('clone').show()
        );
        $('.sortable-placeholder').before(' ').after(' '); // add white space here
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        $('.sortable-placeholder').before(' ').after(' '); // add white space here
        ui.item.before(' ').after(' '); // add white space here
    },
    remove: function(event, ui) {
        $("ul#source > li").removeClass('clone');
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $("ul#source > li.clone").remove();
    },
    placeholder:'sortable-placeholder',

});
```